# Centering image around center of page

Tags: graphics

**Is there an option to align the center of an image with the centre of a page?**

Background: essentially I have got an image that has got some white stuff left and right, while top and bottom is fine as it is. I don't want to crop it, so I thought I could just overscale it slight so that the white stuff falls beyond the margin of the page. But when using `\centering` or `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` I could not achieve the required result since the figure looks like it is bounded by the left margin. Maybe I put the commands in the wrong place though (e.g. should I put it around the figure or around the `\includegraphics`)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Did you try using `\scalebox[1]{horizontal factor}{\includegraphics{…}}`?

Comment: @Bernard that doesnt even compile for me, but Ulrike's answer works perfectly. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a \makebox if you want the graphics to stick out on both sides:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\centering
\makebox[\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=1.5\linewidth]{example-image}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: awesome, works exactly as I wanted, thanks! +1